# converto-html system.object to system.string required by parameter PostContent

Tags: powershell

I am trying to execute a series of steps and create an HTML file. Below is the code:

```
$bkpstat = @()

$a = Get-Date
$b = $a.AddDays(-1)
$b = $b.ToShortDateString();
$StartTime = "10:00:00 PM"
$EndTime = "11:00:00 PM"
$before = $b + " " + $StartTime
$after = $b + " " + $EndTime
$before = [datetime]$before
$after = [datetime]$after


$sms_svc = "SMS Agent Host","SMS_EXECUTIVE","SMS_SITE_COMPONENT_MANAGER","SMS_SITE_VSS_WRITER","SMS_REPORTING_POINT","SMS_SERVER_LOCATOR_POINT"
$smsdb_svc = "SMS Agent Host","SMS_SITE_SQL_BACKUP_WDSMS01"

$style = "<style>$(get-content C:\Temp\Rajiv\style.css)</style>"

$bkpsys = New-Object PSObject
$bkpsys | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name SiteCode -value 000
$bkpstat += $bkpsys

if(Test-Connection WDSMS01 -Count 3 -BufferSize 3 -Quiet)
{
    Write-Host "SMS01 is available. Checking service status"

    $cmsvc_000 = Get-Service $sms_svc -ComputerName SMS01 | Convertto-HTML -Property Name, Status -PreContent "<h2>Service Status for SMS01 </h2>" | Out-String

    Write-Host "Checking Site Server backup for 000"

    $smsbkp_000 = Get-EventLog -ComputerName SMS01 -LogName Application -After $after -Before $before -Source "SMS Server" | ?{$_.EventID -eq 6833} | Select MachineName, Message
    if ($smsbkp_000)
    {
        $bkpsys | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name SiteServer -Value "Success"
    }
    else
    {
        $bkpsys | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name SiteServer -Value "Failed"
    }


}
else
{
    Write-Host "Server SMS01 is not reachable"
    $bkpsys | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name SiteServer -value "Not Reachable"
}

if(Test-Connection SCCMSQL01 -Count 3 -BufferSize 3 -Quiet)
{
    Write-Host "SCCMSQL01 is available. Checking service status"

    $cmdbsvc_000 = Get-Service $smsdb_svc -ComputerName SCCMSQL01 | Convertto-HTML -Property Name, Status -PreContent "<h2>Service Status for SCCMSQL01 </h2>" | Out-String

    Write-Host "Checking Database backup for SMS_000"
    $sqlbkp_000 = Get-EventLog -ComputerName SCCMSQL01 -LogName Application -After $after -Before $before -Source "MSSQLSERVER" | ?{$_.EventID -eq 18264} | Select MachineName, Message
    if ($sqlbkp_000)
    {
        $bkpsys | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Database -value "Success"
    }
    else
    {
        $bkpsys | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name Database -Value "Failed"
    }


}
else
{
    Write-Host "Server SCCMSQL01 is not reachable"
    $bkpsys | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Database -value "Not Reachable"
}
$bkpstat
$params = @{'Head'="<title>Report for ConfigMgr Site 000</title>$style";
    'PreContent'="<h1>Daily Check</h1>";
    'PostContent'=$cmsvc_000, $cmdbsvc_000, $bkpstat} 

 Convertto-HTML @params | Out-File C:\Temp\Rajiv\Site_000.html
```

The error msg that I get is:

ConvertTo-Html : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'PostContent'. Spec
ified method is not supported.
At C:\temp\rajiv\DailyCheck_000.ps1:88 char:16
+  Convertto-HTML <<<<  @params | Out-File C:\Temp\Rajiv\Site_000.html
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertTo-Html], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToHtmlCommand

I have tried using Out-String, with and with out Convertto-HTML for $bkp, in vain. Can some one please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem starts when you define `$bkpstat` as `@()`, which makes it of type `Object[]`. That means when you set `'PostContent'` to `$cmsvc_000, $cmdbsvc_000, $bkpstat` (which have types of `String`, `String`, and `Object[]`) the array that's formed has to be of type `Object[]` instead of `String[]` like you're expecting.

You need to first convert `$bkpstat` to a string to yield the array type the cmdlet is expecting.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I am fairly new to Powershell. Instead I used:
`$bkpstat | Out-File -Append <filename.html>`

How to convert it to String[]?